# Update item in array in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I have an array stored in local storage. once a user navigates to a single item in that array they can add items to a nested array:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "test 1",
    "venue": "test 1",
    "day": "12",
    "month": "January",
    "year": "2016",
    "date": "2016-02-23T14:53:24.118Z",
    "tasks": []
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "test 2",
    "venue": "test 2",
    "day": "22",
    "month": "April",
    "year": "2016",
    "date": "2016-02-23T14:53:24.118Z",
    "tasks": []
}]
```

I have 2 controllers. One that lists all items in the array in ng-repeat and the other to display a single item:

```
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function ($scope, Eventers) {
        $scope.eventers = Eventers.all();
})
```

single item display:

```
.controller('ProfileInnerCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $ionicModal, Eventers) {

 $scope.eventer = Eventers.get($stateParams.eventerId);

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('new-task.html', function(modal) {
        $scope.taskModal = modal;
    }, 
    {
        focusFirstInput: false,
        scope: $scope
    });

$scope.createTask = function(task, index) {

    $scope.eventer.tasks.push({
      title: task.title
    });
    $scope.taskModal.hide();
    Eventers.save($scope.eventer);
    $scope.taskModal.hide();

    };
})
```

and my factory:

```
.factory('Eventers', function() {


    return {
        all: function() {
          var eventerString = window.localStorage['eventers'];
          if (eventerString) {
            return angular.fromJson(eventerString);
          }
          return [];
        },
        save: function(eventers) {
          window.localStorage['eventers'] = angular.toJson(eventers);
        },
        newEventer: function(eventerId, eventerTitle,eventerVenue , eventerDay, eventerMonth, eventerYear, eventerDate) {
            return {
                id: eventerId,
                title: eventerTitle,
                venue: eventerVenue,
                day: eventerDay,
                month: eventerMonth,
                year: eventerYear,
                date: eventerDate,
                tasks: []
            };
        },
        get: function(eventerId){
          var hell = window.localStorage['eventers'];
          var eventers = JSON.parse(hell);

            for (var i = 0; i < eventers.length; i++) {


              if (parseInt(eventers[i].id) === parseInt(eventerId)){
                    console.log(eventerId);
                    return eventers[i];
                }
            }

            return null;
        }


    }

});
```

Once in the single item I want a user to be able to open a modal and add items to the nested tasks array and then update local storage but I cannot seem to wrap my head around it. The way I am doing it now seems to add a task but deletes all other posts in the array.

Comment: No, you don't have a array stored in your local storage. Local storage only accept strings

Comment: please dont make your friends upvote your question for more attention.

Comment: @MikeLammers I did not make anyone upvote my question. or ask any one to upvote my question. I just want an answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

Try to read all the items from the local storage not just parts, then you can add, remove or edit anything without problems. After that, you can proceed to save it.

Answer (score 0):

`Eventers.save($scope.eventer);` 
is saving only the current event.
While the actual implementation is trying to save all

```
save: function(eventers) {
      window.localStorage['eventers'] = angular.toJson(eventers);
    },
```

Thus, its overwriting all the other events.